# How to find an array in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, contains

How do I check if an `Array` contains another `Array`?

jQuery's `$.inArray()` and `array.indexOf([..., ..., ...])` don't work..

Comment: loop through the array, and use `instanceof Array` to check

Comment: Then you use `indexOf`! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your arrays just contain primitives (like strings or numbers) the easiest way is probably to loop through the array and comparing their [string representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
var arr = [ ['one'], ['one', 'three'], ['one', 'two', 'three'] ];
var search = ['one', 'three'];

function arrayInArray(haystack, needle) {
    needle = '' + needle; // needle.toString()
    for(var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if(needle === '' + haystack[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(arrayInArray(arr, search));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the other answer has been accepted but I've typed this out now so might as well post it :)

Comparing string representations is a clever solution but doing it more 'manually' like this may be more readable to the casual observer, or yourself in 6 months...

```
function isArraysEqual(a, b) {
    if(!a || !b || a === b || a.length !=b.length) {
         return false;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function arrayContainsArray(parent, child) {
    for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; ++i) {
        var candidate = parent[i];
        if(candidate instanceof Array && isArraysEqual(candidate, child)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;    
}

var x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var y = [4,5,6];
var z = [10,11,12];   

console.log("should be true: " + arrayContainsArray(x, y));
console.log("should be false: " + arrayContainsArray(x, z));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the code:

```
function equal(a, b) {
    if (a == b) return true;
    if (a instanceof Array && b instanceof Array)
        return a.length == b.length && a.every(
            function (element, index) { return equal(element, b[index]); });
    return false;
}

function positionIf(array, predicate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (predicate(array[i])) break;
    return i;
}

var x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var y = [4, 5, 6];
var z = [10, 11, 12];

function indexOfArray(array, element) {
    return positionIf(
        array, function (searched) { return equal(searched, element); });
}

// >>> indexOfArray(x, y);
// 1
// >>> indexOfArray(x, z);
// 3
```

Explanation:

1. A general `equal` function would be a good thing to have, regardless of other concerns. It's a shame it's not in the standard library. But I believe that many popular multi-purpose libraries provide one.
2. Position-if is a known idiom for doing this kind of operation. You will find an analogous function in standard libraries of many languages, such as for example C++ or Common Lisp. It is good to have one, but probably some library already provides it, so check it (could be Underscore?).
3. Keeping the code more general creates potential for reuse in the future.
4. The index returned is the first index past the boundaries of the array, in case no elements are found. To my best knowledge Donald Knuth first argued this is a more logical thing to do. I won't go into debate about it, I just happen to believe that it is the right thing to do, too.